# Using WHERE with SUM function SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, unique, where-clause

```
    SELECT imagename, SUM(ratingvalue) as "lol"
    FROM ratings
    GROUP BY imagename;
```

[image]

How do I go about grabbing the total of a specific `imagename` so i can then display it onto the page, so for example instead of returning the results for all 12 image name's i want to be able to limit that down to one specific imagename. I would be able to do this if I could use the `WHERE` statement but I realise you cannot do that with aggregate functions.

Any ideas on how I can implement `WHERE imagename = '{$imgname}'` in the above SQL query?

Basically I'm looking for an alternate method to `WHERE`.

Comment: You can use WHERE within a query which is aggregating, but the WHERE will filter for criteria pre-aggregation.  HAVING will filter post-aggregation.  In this case, not sure it matters much, tbh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT imagename, SUM(ratingvalue) as "lol"
FROM ratings
WHERE imagename = 'MyImageName'
GROUP BY imagename;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try HAVING - it's like WHERE but after aggregation.

```
SELECT imagename, SUM(ratingvalue) as "lol"
FROM ratings
GROUP BY imagename
HAVING imagename = 'MyImageName';
```